# How is $-u''(t)/u'(t) > 0$?

Tags: calculus

I am faced with the following problem $-u''(t)/u'(t) > 0$. This equation is in a mathematical article related to soil degeneration. Can someone please explain how this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The negative sign on the left-hand side doesn't mean the left-hand side is negative.  Basically we need $u'(t)$ and $u''(t)$ to have opposite signs.  Then their quotient is negative, and the opposite of it is positive.

So a function $u$ with $u'>0$ and $u''<0$ (i.e., increasing and concave down) will satisfy the inequality.  Or a function with $u'<0$ and $u''>0$ (i.e., decreasing and concave up).

Explicitly, both $u(t) = \sqrt{t}$ and $u(t) =\frac{1}{t}$ would work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't always. ..  we would need to see the function. ..

E.g.  $u(t)=2t $ has $\frac {-u''(t)}{u' (t)}=0$.  Such examples are easy to come by. .

Chances are you have an *exponential* function there...  e. g.  $u(t)=e^{kt} $ has  $u'(t) =ke^{kt} $, and $u''(t)=k^2e^{kt} $.  So $$-\frac {u''(t)}{u'(t)}=-k\gt 0, \forall k \lt0$$...